# Clone user account but change privileges

Tags: users

I have a fully set up admin account on my system (15.04) I daily used.

For security reasons (I know I should have done this long ago, but better now than never), I want to switch over to use a restricted account for everyday work.

What I would like to achieve is to make an exact copy of my current admin profile, give it another name and set its privileges down to "restricted user" without losing any of my configurations, neither system- nor program-related ones.

Can this be done? How?

Comment: How is your admin account different from a standard "first user" account (that has sudo rights)?

Comment: @oli I don't really know what you mean...? I guess there is no real difference at the moment. I have this admin account I created during the installation and another restricted account I never used because I felt too lazy to configure it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

1. Creating a user without admin privileges
2. Creating a user who's a clone of another

Typically, an admin user on Ubuntu is an admin because they are in the `sudo` group. Membership in `sudo` gives you both `sudoers` and Polkit privileges by the default configuration:

```
$ grep %sudo /etc/sudoers
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
$ grep sudo /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf 
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

So, all we need to do is *not* add a new user to the `sudo` group. And that doesn't need anything special to accomplish.

The second part can be handled by either using the normal `adduser` command, and then copy everything in your home directory to theirs' using `rsync` or `cp`, or specifying your home directory as the skeleton directory to `useradd`. The first method would look like:

```
sudo adduser newuser
# answer all the questions
sudo rsync -aP ~bytecommander/ ~newuser
sudo chown newuser -R ~newuser
```

The second would like:

```
sudo useradd -mk ~bytecommander newuser
```

(In both cases, replace `bytecommander` with your username.)

Comment: I probably should have moved my bigger data files somewhere before executing the `useradd...` command >.< Now it's going to take a while...

Comment: You probably want to use `sudo rsync -aPqz ~olduser/ ~newuser` to compress the files and stop printing each file's progress to the console, both of which can improve speed when dealing with folders with lots of small files. 
Also, use `sudo chown newuser:newuser -R ~newuser` to set the owner group.

Comment: @GregRos `-z` compresses data during transfer. For a local transfer it is entirely useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new user.
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   cp --no-dereference --recursive --preserve=timestamps, /home/old_user/* /home/new_user/
   ```
3. Delete the data files from `old_user` that you now don't need any more (documents, pictures, …)

Answer (score 0):

1. From an admin user, create new user (example : 'Joan'). In GUI, u can create it in accounts.
2. Open terminal and go to /home, take note about user and group in the folder /home/joan, and remove it.

   `cd /home`
   `ls -la`
   `sudo rm -rf /home/joan`
3. copy the source user folder to a new user folder, with the same name created before.

   `sudo cp -pPR source_user joan`
4. change user and group with the same as before it was removed.

   `sudo chown -R joan:joan /home/joan`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04, I used these commands:

```
sudo cp -pPr /home/user1 /home/user2 
sudo adduser user2 
chown -R user2 /home/user2
```

Then I went into Settings > Users > verify that user2 is a standard user.